# What is Migration?

Tags: django, django-models, migration

I'm pretty new to Django. When I start an app and run the server, there was a warning that there are "17 unapplied migrations" but I'm not too sure what they mean.

From my research, migration is moving the data between location and app system. When you have a new app installed, it has a new model (which is the way the app interacts with the database). Then you need to apply the difference in models of your previous and new apps to the database structure (database schema). This action is called migration.

I don't know if this is correct. Can you explain more of this to me? 
Also, what does the computer do when it applies a migration? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Migrations are Django's way of documenting and adding changes that you make to your models into your database. The reason you need to make migrations is because you have made changes to your model and have not propagated them to your database. Please read this for more info as it will give you much more info than anyone on this site: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/

Comment: What will happen if I have changed the model but I don't map these changes to the database?

Answer (score 1):

Migrations are Django’s way of propagating changes you make to your models (adding a field, deleting a model, etc.) into your database schema. They’re designed to be mostly automatic, but you’ll need to know when to make migrations, when to run them, and the common problems you might run into.

To prepare the migrations files run the below command. It's kind of like preparing the migrations to be applied.

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

To actually commit the migrations to your database run the below command:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: So when you apply a new system, first you need to make migration (find the changes in the model and figure how to adapt the database accordingly to those changes) and then apply migration (change the database structure or schema). Ok nice, thank you!

Comment: Yes right and also if someone helps you on stackoverflow you upvote his answer.

Comment: I try to upvote but my reputation score is below 15 so it is not recorded lol. I will try again later.